# How to Average Number of Chats per Day on LEFT JOIN table in Snowflake SQL?

Tags: sql, date, sum, average, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake SQL dictation, how do I average the number of video chats per day using a field from a table I left joined to the entire query?

I'm thinking I have to do a SUM function to total the number of video chats and then aggregate by # of video chats for each date and then divide by 30 days (the rolling date range I specified throughout my entire query).

Any help would be appreciated as deadlines are approaching. Thank you.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        t1."pid",
        IFNULL(t2."VideoChats",0),
        t3."SFUser",
        t3."TotalProviders",
        t4."dimaccount.practice_specialty",
        t5."Account: CMRR",
        t6."CreatedDate",
        t7."stg_sf_case.Date_Time_Resolved__c",
        t8."stg_sf_case.Closed_Date",
        t9."pid"
    FROM (SELECT "pid"
            FROM "EDW_PROD"."PUBLIC"."STG_MYSQL_PROVIDERMODULES" AS a
            WHERE a."active" 
              AND a."status" = 'PURCHASED'
              AND a."module_id" = '14'
            GROUP BY a."pid"
            ) t1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT "started_at",
                    "pid",
                    COUNT(*) AS "VideoChats"
                FROM "EDW_PROD"."PUBLIC"."STG_MYSQL_VIDEOCHATROOM" AS b
                LEFT JOIN "EDW_PROD"."PUBLIC"."DIMACCOUNT" AS dimaccount 
                    ON b."pid" = dimaccount."PID"
                WHERE b."started_at"  >= DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE())
                  AND b."started_at" < DATEADD('month', 1, DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE()))
                  AND dimaccount."CurrentRow" = 'Y'
                GROUP BY b."pid", b."started_at"
            ) t2 ON t1."pid" = t2."pid"
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results to clarify your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

For a rolling average you probably want to use a window function. Something along these lines.

```
SELECT AVG(VideoChats) over (partition by pid order by started_at rows between 30 preceding and current row) as AvgVideoChats

--I saw a post about AVG not allowing a sliding window, so you may have to do this instead
SELECT SUM(VideoChats) over (partition by pid order by started_at rows between 30 preceding and current row) / 30. as AvgVideoChats
```

You may need to do this in a wrapper around your `t2` query and adjust your date filters so that there are values available for averaging, but I'm not quite clear enough on what your query is doing with dates, or what results you are looking for, to be sure.